# HTTP Authorization conditional rule for Apache 2.4

Tags: html, regex, apache

Does anyone know how to access to HTTP Authorization header with apache 2.4 ?
I tried but without success with these lines:

```
<If "%{HTTP:AUTHORIZATION} =~ /Basic dW5kZWZpbmVkOnNlc3Npb24=/">
   Redirect "/" "https://url.realm"
</If>
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind clicking the [edit] link to edit that info into your question?

Comment: What "programming language" are you trying to solve that problem in? I assume it's inside a `.htaccess` file... have you tried with the case-sensitive `Authorization`?

Comment: It's directly on Virtual Host, yes I already tried with your suggestion but it still not works, Apache said to me that it's not an existing variable

Comment: Still not working? Do you use  Apache mod_proxy_fcgi PHP-FPM or ProxyMassMatch?

Comment: Yes still not working, I am using mod_proxy_fcgi now.